# RTF to HTML, change font-family

Tags: c#, html, rtf

I have some RTF text from my C# application which I convert to HTML and then send to my PHP file.
Problem is; all my text in PHP is in Arial, The output of my RTF is Tahoma. Any ideas how I can change the font-family?

This is my code so far:

```
string memoValue = inboundSet.Fields["MEMO"].Value.ToString();
if (RtfTags.IsRtfContent(memoValue))
  {     
    using (RichEditDocumentServer richServer = new RichEditDocumentServer())
      {
        string htmlText = string.Empty;
        richServer.RtfText = memoValue;
        htmlText = richServer.HtmlText;
        callDetail.Memo = htmlText;
      }
  }
else
  {
    callDetail.Memo = memoValue;
  }
```

In my PHP file I get the value in this way:

```
echo "<td>Memo:</td><td>".$value->Memo."</td>";
```

I also tried it in this way:

```
echo "<td>Memo:</td><td class='fonttest'>".$value->Memo."</td>";
```

And in my CSS:

```
.fonttest
{
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Arial;
}
```

My text keeps looking like this:

[image]

This is what my RTF text looks like:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to change `Times New Roman` and `Calibri` to `Arial`? Just a simple thing I need to ask :)

Comment: I solved it already. I can't change the RTF manually since I don't have direct access in the code of the C# application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by this way:

```
string memoValue = inboundSet.Fields["MEMO"].Value.ToString();
if (RtfTags.IsRtfContent(memoValue))
{     
  using (RichEditDocumentServer richServer = new RichEditDocumentServer())
  {
    string htmlText = string.Empty;
    richServer.RtfText = memoValue;
    CharacterProperties cp = richServer.Document.BeginUpdateCharacters(richServer.Document.Range);
    cp.FontName = "Arial";
    cp.FontSize = 12;
    richServer.Document.EndUpdateCharacters(cp);
    htmlText = richServer.HtmlText;
    callDetail.Memo = htmlText;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set font-family for your generated HTML. You can do so by applying CSS style to the header of geneted page.

Embed this style to the header:

```
"<style>body {font-family:Arial;}</style>"
```

Comment: I don't convert a whole page, it's most likely just 1 sentence. In my CSS of my PHP page I have indeed font-family:arial, but it seems that the sentence I got from my converter doesn't care about stylesheets